# Use Twig variable as a property name of an other Twig variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I must use a Twig variable as a property for another Twig variable.

In a for loop, I get the properties of a specific entity and want to use those properties to get the property-content for an entity variable in an other for loop.

Some code to make this clear:

```
{% for entity in entities  %}

{{entity.foo}}, {{entity.bar}}<br />

{% for property in specialdynamicproperties %}
{{entity.property}} <!-- property has the content foobar for example, I want to use it as the property accessor for entity -->
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)?

Comment: @mbosecke: this works for me, just write it as an answer so I can accept it, thank you :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [attribute function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html) is what you are looking for.

Edit:

```
  {{ attribute(object, method) }}
  {{ attribute(object, method, arguments) }}
  {{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

Comment: Link in answer is broken - look [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html)

Answer (score 19):

```
    {% for object in objects %}
        {% for column in columns %}
            {{ attribute(object, column) }} {# equivalent to php $object[$column] #}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Using Twig [Attribute Function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) (Twig > 1.2)